# Looping through snapshot .values is random?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the bellow function which is supposed to loop through the media in a listing post to get "stats" like `likes` and `numComments`. The problem, however, is that the loop which starts: `for val in mediaDict` seems to loop randomly like the following *media4{}, media2{}*... instead of: media1{} 2 and so on.

**How can I fix this?**

I tried fixing this by getting the value of media num and passing it into the array of media objects, and yet I think even they are in random order The perfect solution would be to have the firebase function loop in correct order.

```
var indexForStats = 0

func getMediaStats() {
    print("stats index val", indexForStats)

    
    databaseRef.child("MediaStats").child((post?.user.userID)!).child(postPath).observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value) { (snap) in
        print(snap, " This is the snapshot")
        
        if snap.value is NSNull {
            print("No stats (comments or likes)")
        } else {
            let mediaDict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
            
            for val in mediaDict {
                let mediaString = val.key
                let lastCharacter = mediaString.last
                let mediaNumber = Int(String(lastCharacter!))

                print(val, " This sis val !!!")
                let statsDict = val.value as! [String: Int]
                
                print(mediaNumber!, " This is the media number")

                if statsDict["likes"] != nil {
                    let likes = statsDict["likes"]!
                    self.post?.media[mediaNumber! - 1].likes = likes
                } else {
                    print("No likes while fetching")
                    self.post?.media[mediaNumber! - 1].likes = 0
                }
                
                if statsDict["numComments"] != nil {
                    let comments = statsDict["numComments"]!
                    self.post?.media[mediaNumber! - 1].numberComments = comments
                } else {
                    print("No comments")
                    self.post?.media[mediaNumber! - 1].numberComments = 0
                }
                
                self.indexForStats += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output: of print(mediaNumber, "This sis teh media number")**

> Optional(3)  This sis the media number
>
> Optional(1)  This sis teh media number
> ...

Comment: Use queryOrdered(byChild:).

Comment: @ElTomato how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee of the order of entries in a dictionary. Only that each unique key will return the corresponding value.

And, yes, it will appear random since it depends on the hash of the key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1. Tell Firebase in what order to return the children.
2. Loop over `DataSnapshot.children` to ensure you handle them order.

In code:

```
databaseRef.child("MediaStats").child((post?.user.userID)!).child(postPath)
  queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value) { (snap) in
    print(snap, " This is the snapshot")

    if !snap.exists() {
        print("No stats (comments or likes)")
    } else {
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            print(child.key)
            let statsDict = child.value as! [String: Int]
            print(statsDict["likes"])
        }
    }
```